# React Native: add the symbol to delete when writing inside an input text

Tags: javascript, react-native

I would like to insert the ' x ' only when at least one letter is typed into the text input. I was able to add it even when the text input is empty, but I would like the 'x' not to be there when the input is empty.

The code:

```
 //...

  const [textArtist, onChangeTextArtist] = useState('');

  const RightIcon = () => {
    if (textArtist != '') {
      <MaterialIcons
        name='highlight-remove'
        color='grey'
        size={24}
        onPress={() => onChangeTextArtist('')}
      />
    }
  }

  return (
    //...

      <Input
        placeholder="Artist's name here..."
        onChangeText={onChangeTextArtist}
        value={textArtist}
        errorMessage={errorMessage}
        rightIcon={RightIcon}         // <---- here
      />

 //...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This..

```
const RightIcon = () => {
    if (textArtist.length) {
      <MaterialIcons
        name='highlight-remove'
        color='grey'
        size={24}
        onPress={() => onChangeTextArtist('')}
      />
    }
  }
```